# Fandom-py: Unable to get image by using page.images[0]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, mediawiki, wiki

I'm using [fandom module](https://fandom-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in python for my discord bot. I get this error when I request data by using `page.images[0]`. It should be an image url. This is [the page](https://soul-knight.fandom.com/wiki/Anubis) I want to get.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\fandom\util.py", line 90, in _wiki_request
    r = r.json()
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 901, in json
    return complexjson.loads(
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 168, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\billy\bot.py", line 83, in sk
    embed.set_image(url=page.images[0])
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\fandom\FandomPage.py", line 324, in images
    request = _wiki_request(query_params)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\fandom\util.py", line 92, in _wiki_request
    raise RequestError(api_url, params)
fandom.error.RequestError: Your request to the url "https://soul-knight.fandom.com/en/api.php" with the paramaters "{'action': 'query', 'prop': 'imageinfo', 'imlimit': 500, 'titles': ['File:Angry.png', 'File:Anubis.png', 'File:Anubis fragment.png', 'File:BossPRVW.png', 'File:MoreElite.png', 'File:Sprite AbyssKnight BlueSpear.png', 'File:Sprite AbyssKnight GreenSpear.png', 'File:Sprite AbyssKnight RedSpear.png', 'File:Sprite AmphibianPirate.png', 'File:Sprite Anubis.png', 'File:Sprite Cave Ice Bug.png', 'File:Sprite CodeNameDancer.png', 'File:Sprite Crystal Giant.png', 'File:Sprite Crystal Giant Jr.png', 'File:Sprite Dark Grand Knight.png', 'File:Sprite Dark Knight.png', 'File:Sprite Easter Bunny.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Goblin Archer.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Grave Skeleton Javelin.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Grave Skeleton Mace.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Grave Skeleton Sword.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Monkey AK47.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Monkey Firework.png', 'File:Sprite Explosive Worker.png', 'File:Sprite Fire Goblin Priest.png', 'File:Sprite FloatingLaserCrabMPT.png', 'File:Sprite Floating UFO.png', 'File:Sprite Giant Golden Crab.png', 'File:Sprite Goblin Artist.png', 'File:Sprite Gold Mask.png', 'File:Sprite Grand Knight alt.png', 'File:Sprite Grand Slime.png', 'File:Sprite Grand Wizard.png', 'File:Sprite Grave Guard Scarab Archon.png', 'File:Sprite Grave Robber.png', 'File:Sprite Grave Skeleton Bow.png', 'File:Sprite Grave Skeleton Staff.png', 'File:Sprite Guard Crab.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Axe.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Blowpipe.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Bow.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Giant.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin GoblinSpear.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Pioneer.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Priest.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Shaman.png', 'File:Sprite Haunted Goblin Shotgun.png', 'File:Sprite Ice Bug Larva.png', 'File:Sprite IronPirateKingLevel.png', 'File:Sprite Lord of Infinite Dark.png', 'File:Sprite Manned Mecha Guardian Cannon.png', 'File:Sprite Manned Mecha Guardian Drill.png', 'File:Sprite Mega Mining Extractor Cannon.png', 'File:Sprite Mega Mining Extractor Claw.png', 'File:Sprite Miner Lead Beam Gun.png', 'File:Sprite Miner Lead Pickaxe.png', 'File:Sprite Mining Electrician.png', 'File:Sprite Monkey Club.png', 'File:Sprite Monkey Poo.png', 'File:Sprite Monkey Vine.png', 'File:Sprite Mushroom Baby.png', 'File:Sprite Mushroom Man.png', 'File:Sprite Nian.png', 'File:Sprite PirateARifle.png', 'File:Sprite PirateASawed-off.png', 'File:Sprite PirateAScimitar.png', 'File:Sprite PirateBoxerModel.png', 'File:Sprite Prehistoric Colossus.png', 'File:Sprite Rock Crab.png', 'File:Sprite SOFinfantryPirate.png', 'File:Sprite Scarab Blue.png', 'File:Sprite Scarab Green.png', 'File:Sprite Scarab Red.png', 'File:Sprite SentryOwlPilot.png', 'File:Sprite Sir Sangria.png', 'File:Sprite Sir Violet.png', 'File:Sprite Skeleton Doggy.png', 'File:Sprite Skeleton King alt.png', 'File:Sprite Snow Ape Pitcher.png', 'File:Sprite Stone Archer.png', 'File:Sprite Stone Guard Melee.png', 'File:Sprite Stone Guard Turret.png', 'File:Sprite Tentacle of the Past.png', 'File:Sprite The Giant.png', 'File:Sprite Top Gun.png', 'File:Sprite Toxic Worm.png', 'File:Sprite alienlaser.png', 'File:Sprite alienshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite aliensword.png', 'File:Sprite babysnowape.png', 'File:Sprite battery.png', 'File:Sprite bigskeleton.png', 'File:Sprite bigsoldier.png', 'File:Sprite boar.png', 'File:Sprite boomerangcactus.png', 'File:Sprite burningbeetle.png', 'File:Sprite c6h8o6.png', 'File:Sprite chester.png', 'File:Sprite chesterblue.png', 'File:Sprite christmastreant.png', 'File:Sprite crystalbeetle.png', 'File:Sprite crystalmine.png', 'File:Sprite devilsnare.png', 'File:Sprite direboar.png', 'File:Sprite dragonblack.png', 'File:Sprite dragonwhite.png', 'File:Sprite elitegoblinguardblowpipe.png', 'File:Sprite elitegoblinguardscythe.png', 'File:Sprite elitegoblinguardshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite eliteknightrifle.png', 'File:Sprite eliteknightshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite eliteknightsword.png', 'File:Sprite eliteminerrifle.png', 'File:Sprite eliteminerrocket.png', 'File:Sprite eliteminershotgun.png', 'File:Sprite elitemummygun.png', 'File:Sprite elitemummystaff.png', 'File:Sprite elitepumpkinrifle.png', 'File:Sprite elitepumpkinscythe.png', 'File:Sprite elitepumpkinshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite eliteskeletonrifle.png', 'File:Sprite eliteskeletonshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite eliteskeletonsword.png', 'File:Sprite flameknightcaptain.png', 'File:Sprite flameknighthammer.png', 'File:Sprite flameknightspear.png', 'File:Sprite frog.png', 'File:Sprite giantcrystalcrab.png', 'File:Sprite goblinfly.png', 'File:Sprite goblingiant.png', 'File:Sprite goblinguardbow.png', 'File:Sprite goblinguardpistol.png', 'File:Sprite goblinguardspear.png', 'File:Sprite goblinpriest.png', 'File:Sprite goblinshaman.png', 'File:Sprite goblinwalk.png', 'File:Sprite goldenbeetle.png', 'File:Sprite goldmine.png', 'File:Sprite gunshark.png', 'File:Sprite headlessknight.png', 'File:Sprite kingsnowape.png', 'File:Sprite knightpistol.png', 'File:Sprite knightsmg.png', 'File:Sprite knightsword.png', 'File:Sprite lavabeehive.png', 'File:Sprite mineraxe.png', 'File:Sprite minerdrill.png', 'File:Sprite minergun.png', 'File:Sprite mummybomb.png', 'File:Sprite mummygun.png', 'File:Sprite mummygunbounce.png', 'File:Sprite phantom.png', 'File:Sprite phantomking.png', 'File:Sprite poisonspider.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkincoach.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkinfork.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkinpistol.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkinscythe.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonbow.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonshaman.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonsword.png', 'File:Sprite slime.png', 'File:Sprite snowape.png', 'File:Sprite snowmanking.png', 'File:Sprite spider.png', 'File:Sprite starfish.png', 'File:Sprite tentacle.png', 'File:Sprite transitiondevice.png', 'File:Sprite trumpetflower.png', 'File:Sprite ufo.png', 'File:Sprite varkolyn.png', 'File:Sprite varkolynguardaxe.png', 'File:Sprite varkolynguardgun.png', 'File:Sprite varkolynleader.png', 'File:Sprite volcanicbug.png', 'File:Sprite volcanicsandworm.png', 'File:Sprite volcanicturtle.png', 'File:Sprite witch.png', 'File:Sprite wizarde.png', 'File:Sprite zombie.png', 'File:Sprite zulan.png', 'File:Torn page Pray.png', 'File:Turret.png'], 'iilimit': 5000, 'iiprop': 'url', 'format': 'json'}" either returned nothing or returned data in a format other than JSON. Please check your input data.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1033, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 933, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "D:\Desktop\coding\discordpy\env\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 177, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RequestError: Your request to the url "https://soul-knight.fandom.com/en/api.php" with the paramaters "{'action': 'query', 'prop': 'imageinfo', 'imlimit': 500, 'titles': ['File:Angry.png', 'File:Anubis.png', 'File:Anubis fragment.png', 'File:BossPRVW.png', 'File:MoreElite.png', 'File:Sprite AbyssKnight BlueSpear.png', 'File:Sprite AbyssKnight GreenSpear.png', 'File:Sprite AbyssKnight RedSpear.png', 'File:Sprite AmphibianPirate.png', 'File:Sprite Anubis.png', 'File:Sprite Cave Ice Bug.png', 'File:Sprite CodeNameDancer.png', 'File:Sprite Crystal Giant.png', 'File:Sprite Crystal Giant Jr.png', 'File:Sprite Dark Grand Knight.png', 'File:Sprite Dark Knight.png', 'File:Sprite Easter Bunny.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Goblin Archer.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Grave Skeleton Javelin.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Grave Skeleton Mace.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Grave Skeleton Sword.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Monkey AK47.png', 'File:Sprite Elite Monkey Firework.png', 'File:Sprite Explosive Worker.png', 'File:Sprite Fire Goblin Priest.png', 'File:Sprite FloatingLaserCrabMPT.png', 'File:Sprite Floating UFO.png', 'File:Sprite Giant Golden Crab.png', 'File:Sprite Goblin Artist.png', 'File:Sprite Gold Mask.png', 'File:Sprite Grand Knight alt.png', 'File:Sprite Grand Slime.png', 'File:Sprite Grand Wizard.png', 'File:Sprite Gng', 'File:Sprite flameknighthammer.png', 'File:Sprite flameknightspear.png', 'File:Sprite frog.png', 'File:Sprite giantcrystalcrab.png', 'File:Sprite goblinfly.png', 'File:Sprite goblingiant.png', 'File:Sprite goblinguardbow.png', 'File:Sprite goblinguardpistol.png', 'File:Sprite goblinguardspear.png', 'File:Sprite goblinpriest.png', 'File:Sprite goblinshaman.png', 'File:Sprite goblinwalk.png', 'File:Sprite goldenbeetle.png', 'File:Sprite goldmine.png', 'File:Sprite gunshark.png', 'File:Sprite headlessknight.png', 'File:Sprite kingsnowape.png', 'File:Sprite knightpistol.png', 'File:Sprite knightsmg.png', 'File:Sprite knightsword.png', 'File:Sprite lavabeehive.png', 'File:Sprite mineraxe.png', 'File:Sprite minerdrill.png', 'File:Sprite minergun.png', 'File:Sprite mummybomb.png', 'File:Sprite mummygun.png', 'File:Sprite mummygunbounce.png', 'File:Sprite phantom.png', 'File:Sprite phantomking.png', 'File:Sprite poisonspider.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkincoach.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkinfork.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkinpistol.png', 'File:Sprite pumpkinscythe.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonbow.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonshaman.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonshotgun.png', 'File:Sprite skeletonsword.png', 'File:Sprite slime.png', 'File:Sprite snowape.png', 'File:Sprite snowmanking.png', 'File:Sprite spider.png', 'File:Sprite starfish.png', 'File:Sprite tentacle.png', 'File:Sprite transitiondevice.png', 'File:Sprite trumpetflower.png', 'File:Sprite ufo.png', 'File:Sprite varkolyn.png', 'File:Sprite varkolynguardaxe.png', 'File:Sprite varkolynguardgun.png', 'File:Sprite varkolynleader.png', 'File:Sprite volcanicbug.png', 'File:Sprite volcanicsandworm.png', 'File:Sprite volcanicturtle.png', 'File:Sprite witch.png', 'File:Sprite wizarde.png', 'File:Sprite zombie.png', 'File:Sprite zulan.png', 'File:Torn page Pray.png', 'File:Turret.png'], 'iilimit': 5000, 'iiprop': 'url', 'format': 'json'}" either returned nothing or returned data in a format other than JSON. Please check your input data.
```

Can annyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using [pymediawiki](https://pypi.org/project/pymediawiki/) module.

This code that use mediawiki can replace fandom module by changing the api of wiki.

```py
sk_fandom = MediaWiki(url='https://soul-knight.fandom.com/api.php')
```